# Prolog Lists - Duplicate head

Tags: prolog, clpfd, list

I am trying to make a list of 2 consecutive terms from a list of terms. So echo should return True if L1 and L2 are lists and L2 contains each element in L1 twice in a row.
Without clpfd.

I want echo to take in...

```
echo([x,1,[b]], L).
```

and return...

```
L = [x,x,1,1,[b],[b]].
```

It does work with...

```
echo([2,1],[2,2,1,1]).
true.
```

This is what I have so far...

```
echo([],[]).
echo([X|XS], [Y,Z|YZS]) :-
    X #= Y,
    Y #= Z,
    echo(XS, YZS).
```

I get back an error regarding terms =>

```
Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `x'
```

Comment: You need to note upfront that this is using `clpfd`. Big difference between Prolog and Prolog with clpfd.

Comment: Is `clpfd` required for the answer? You did not explicitly say in the question. I ask because this is much easier without `clpfd`.

Comment: CLP(FD) (operators such as `#=`) is for reasoning over integers only. Thus the "domain error".

Comment: fixed without clpfd, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't want to use CLPFD.

Without CLPFD:

```
echo([], []).
echo([X|Xs], [X,X|Ys]):-
  echo(Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: Sure you answer while I fix the question. :(